Connect Timeout expired. Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts
I'm trying to deploy my api inside a docker container. It was working perfectly but I changed the mysql server parameters and it started giving me the following problem. Does anyone have any idea what could be happening. Thanks in advance.

#15 [life-tech build 9/9] RUN dotnet-ef database update
#15 2.302 Build started...
#15 15.06 Build succeeded.
#15 15.89 Connection String: Server=server-database;Database=db;Uid=user;Pwd=password;Port=3306;default command timeout=60
#15 31.24 MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Connect Timeout expired.
#15 31.24  ---> MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
#15 31.24    at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ConnectAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in //src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 432
#15 31.24    at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.ConnectSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, String logMessage, Int32 startTickCount, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in //src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 363
#15 31.24    at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in //src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 94
#15 31.24    at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in //src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 124
#15 31.24    at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(ConnectionPool pool, Int32 startTickCount, Nullable1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 911 #15 31.24    at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(ConnectionPool pool, Int32 startTickCount, Nullable1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 933

Locally it works perfectly.

PM> update-database
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Connection String: Server=xxxxxxx;Database=xxxxxx;Uid=xxxxxx;Pwd=xxxxxxxxxxx;Port=3306
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
Entity Framework Core 6.0.0 initialized 'DbContext' using provider 'Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql:6.0.0' with options: ServerVersion 8.0.35-mysql
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
Executed DbCommand (217ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='xxxxxxx' AND TABLE_NAME='__EFMigrationsHistory';
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
Executed DbCommand (180ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='xxxxxxx' AND TABLE_NAME='__EFMigrationsHistory';
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
Executed DbCommand (185ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT MigrationId, ProductVersion
FROM __EFMigrationsHistory
ORDER BY MigrationId;
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations[20405]
No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.
No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.
Done.
PM>

You should make the connection and run some test queries.
Pipeline log

Is the database running on the host? Or in another Docker container using docker compose?

Can you increase the connection timeout to see if it helps?  In the local you have 30 seconds, maybe it takes longer to do it remotely, so see if increasing the timeout gives it enough time to finish before throwing an error.

The database is running into Amazon RDS
